# Can you pass form variables and a json object at the same time using HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3, httpwebrequest

I need to post a json string and a form variable to a url (https://www.somedomain.com/checkout.jsp).

My json will contain order information (user email, shipping address, billing address, credit card number, etc).  In addition to the json string I need to pass in a form variable like "bmForm=submit_order_service."

Currently I am attempting to do this via the HttpWebRequest object in ASP.Net MVC 3 (C#).

Here is the code that handles just the json string.  So, my question is, how do I modify this code to also pass in the form variable as well.

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.somedomain.com/checkout/checkout.jsp");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.Accept = "*/*";
httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "SomeUserAgent";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = sb.ToString();
    streamWriter.Write(json);
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

If it's not possible to do what I am asking using HttpWebRequest, maybe someone can recommend an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can HTML encode your form data and append it to the URL as parameters : `http://www.somedomain.com/checkout/checkout.jsp?param1=value1&param2=value2...` . Basically, treat the form as if its action is set to GET (but use the POST HTTP verb, of course).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have both the Json and the form parameters inside the "Post-Data" you're going to have to urlencode your json and add it as a form parameter along with the other form parameters:

e.g.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://mysite.com/index.php");
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string postData = "json=[yoururlencodedjson]&var2=value2&var3=value3"
req.ContentLength = postData.Length;
```

Essentially you will need to find out from the service provider which format they expect.